# How to change Leiningen dependency tree

Tags: java, postgresql, clojure

I am using [korma "0.4.0"] in my project.

And this version of Korma, by default, uses c3p0-​*0.9.1.2*​

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770550/createarrayof-abstractmethoderror) SO post, I need c3p0-​*0.9.5.1*​ to be able to use `createArrayOf` on a `NewProxyConnection`. I'm doing this because I need to be able to insert PostGre SQL arrays.

For the purpose of completeness, my code used to convert from a Clojure vector to an SQL Array object in Java is the following:

```
(.createArrayOf
  (-> db get-connection :datasource .getConnection)
  "varchar"
  (into-array String someVector)
)
```

Also, the error I am getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.createArrayOf

Which is the same as the error mentioned in that same SO post I mentioned above.

How do I alter the dependency tree such that Korma is *forced* to use c3p0-​*0.9.5.1* instead of c3p0-​*0.9.1.2*​?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `project.clj`, ask for the version which you need, and for good measure it's often helpful to exclude the dependency from the project which asks for the wrong version.

```
:dependencies [[com.mchange/c3p0 "0.9.5.1"]
               [korma "0.4.2"
                :exclusions [c3p0]]]
```

The dependency resolver will respect top level dependencies over nested ones, and `:exclusions` will prevent the version asked for by a specific dep from being used.

Comment: I tried it but Korma still uses the same version.
Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2

Comment: Here are my dependencies -- is anything wrong?

`:dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
    [enlive "1.1.5"]
    [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
    [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.3-1104-jdbc4"]
    [com.mchange/c3p0 "0.9.5.1"]
    [korma "0.4.0"
      :exclusions [com.mchange/c3p0]
    ]
    [raven-clj "1.4.1"]
  ]`

Comment: you might find it useful to look at the output of `lein deps :tree` to see where the version conflicts are introduced

Comment: Thank you. Korma requires c3p0 and not the one with the namespace. Strange. What do you think?
[com.mchange/c3p0 "0.9.5.1"]
   [com.mchange/mchange-commons-java "0.2.10"]
 [korma "0.4.2" :exclusions [[com.mchange/c3p0]]]
   [c3p0 "0.9.1.2"]
   [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.7"]

Comment: The correct way to do it is `:exclusions [c3p0]` Kindly change your answer and I will accept it.